# Have first flex columns height capped by second flex item

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```
<div style="display: flex;">
  <div style="display: flex; flex: 1; background: red;">
    <div style="height: 500px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="display: flex; flex: 2; background: black;">
    <div style="height: 300px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a scenario where I need the first columns height to be determined by the height of the second column. Both column heights are dynamic, in this case the second column has content inside of height `300px` and the first column has content of height `500px`. I want to set the max height of column 1 to the height of column 2, and set the overflow to scroll.